# how to make Cortana take over my device

Tags: cortana, windows-8

I have enabled Cortana on my device. I want to enable Cortana at lock screen. I want Cortana to pick my search queries when I say something like "OK GOOGLE" in Google Now. I don't want to click on Cortana tile again and again to start using it. I also want to know all the shortcuts for using cortana. Is there any keyword that I need to say to wake up cortana?

I named it `Jarvis`. If there is any keyword like `Hey Jarvis` or something, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Lockscreen**

You can do this by going to Cortana's settings and allowing Cortana even when the screen is locked.

**Waking Up**

If your phone supports it, you can turn on "Hey Cortana" in Settings. You will need the Lumia Denim update for this. You can check availability at https://www.microsoft.com/en/mobile/support/software-update/wp8-software-update.

Note that your "Jarvis" name will have no effect. She is still named Cortana. (I'm guessing that you actually named *yourself* Jarvis :).) Therefore it will still be "Hey Cortana".

You can also press the Search button to start Cortana, or hold it to start talking to her.